# How to sum the amount and merge the offers in a single row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, querying

I have table with discount transactions data as below:

| TransactionID | DiscountAmount | DiscountOffer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S011-T012 | 50 | Jun-21 |
| S011-T012 | 25 | ManagerDisc |
| S011-T025 | 15 | Jul-21 |

I need to create a table in a way that for a single transaction, Discount amount is summed up and Discount offer is shown side-by-side (maybe with a delimiter between them). For example:

| TransactionID | DiscountAmount | DiscountOffer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S011-T012 | 75 | Jun-21 / ManagerDisc |
| S011-T025 | 15 | Jul-21 |

I'm able to sum the discount amounts but having a hard time merging the offers.

Can someone provide any tips on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY`, as in:

```
select
  TransactionID,
  sum(DiscountAmount) as DiscountAmount,
  string_agg(DiscountOffer, ' / ') as DiscountOffer
from t
group by TransactionID
```